# Solr is giving me the results without white spaces for autosuggest

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, solr

I am new to SOLR. we have a requirement to show auto suggestions.I have implemented the solr auto suggest. But, while executing the auto suggest query, I am getting the response without white spaces.

Where as, when i execute the select query, i can able to see the original data.

I have tried with "WhitespaceTokenizerFactory", and "StandardTokenizerFactory" in schema.xml. But still having the same problem.

Below is my schema.xml, and solrconfig.xml files.

### **schema.xml**

```
<analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>

<analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

### **solrconfig.xml:**

```
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="autosuggest">
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">autosuggest</str>
      <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst.AnalyzingLookupFactory</str>
      <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
      <str name="storeDir">autosuggest</str>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
      <str name="field">content</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_asug</str>

      <bool name="preserveSep">true</bool>
      <!-- Suggester properties 
      <bool name="exactMatchFirst">true</bool>-->
    </lst>
</searchComponent>
<requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/autosuggest">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">autosuggest</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>autosuggest</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

and the response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">2</int>
    </lst>

    <lst name="spellcheck">
        <lst name="suggestions">
            <lst name="venusPressRelease">
                <int name="numFound">1</int>
                <int name="startOffset">9</int>
                <int name="endOffset">26</int>
                <arr name="suggestion">
                    <str>venuspressrelease</str>
                </arr>

            </lst>
            <str name="collation">content:"venuspressrelease"</str>
        </lst>
    </lst>
</response>
```

Expected response is:

```
<arr name="suggestion">
    <str>venus press release</str>
</arr>
```

Can anyone please suggest where the problem is ?

Comment: may i know what is the problem?

Comment: when i type 'venu' in the search text, I am getting suggestion as 'venuspressrelease'. 
But I want response like 'venus press release'.

Comment: Did you get any solutions to this?